# Javascript not interpreted after ajax call

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am making a wordpress website and i got a problem. I added a social button to share post on several socials websites.

I also made an infinite scroll loading next posts. My problem is that this javascript is not interpreted when i put the html callback into my page. This button is making with javascript.

My ajax call return me all the html of a wordpress page (with html tag...)

Here is my javascript code :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

            // Are there more posts to load?
            if(pageNum <= max) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url:nextLink,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success : function(data) {
                        // Update page number and nextLink.
                        pageNum++;
                        nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);
                        var pageN = pageNum-1;
                        var div = $(data).find('.my-post-format');

                        // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                            .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
                    }


                });
            }
        }
    });
```

My html code :

```
<!-- Lockerz Share BEGIN -->
                    <li id="partager-article"> <a class="a2a_dd" href="http://www.addtoany.com/share_save?linkurl=<?php the_title() ?>&amp;linkname=<?php the_permalink() ?>">share</a>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                   var a2a_config = a2a_config || {};
                   a2a_config.linkname = "<?php the_title() ?>";
                   a2a_config.linkurl = "<?php the_permalink() ?>";
                   a2a_config.locale = "fr";
                   a2a_config.num_services = 6;
                   </script>
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
                   <!-- Lockerz Share END --></li>
```

In my data variable, i have my  tag, but when i do $(data), this tags disappear.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a containing div and adding the data to it, like

```
$('<div />').html(data)
```